# Mstest test kills process after completion of test

Tags: c#, mstest

I have a report (.html) file which I open when all my tests have executed. I have written the following code for the same:

```
[ClassCleanup]
public  void CleanUp()
{
    var sUrl ="\\PerfReport\\PerformanceTestReport.html";
    Process.Start(sUrl);
}
```

The issue is - when the test completes, the browser window is closed also.

I don't want this browser window to be closed.

Any suggestion why this is happening? I tried the same behavior in a console application; the browser is not closed there.

Comment: ClaenUp must be static, did you miss that when posting the question? Apart from that, this works fine for me...

Comment: Perhaps, instead of opening the URL via "test cleanup", create some kind of Visual Studio macro that first executes your tests, then opens that document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making cmd a parent of your process.

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo { Arguments = "/C '"+sUrl+"'", FileName = "cmd", WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden });
```